# How to Sort List of Queue of Custom Class by sum of any int property in c#

Tags: c#, lambda

I have to SORT list of Queue of custom class by sum of integer property(in my example it is totalitems).

**Sleeper.cs:**

```
class Sheeple
{     
    public int totalItem { get; private set; }
}
```

And in Form.cs file, I need to sort

```
List<Queue<Sheeple>> sheepleList = new List<Queue<Sheeple>>();

if (sheepleList.Any(i => i.Count < 6)) {
       sheepleList = sheepleList.Sort(i => i.Sum(j => j.totalItem));
}
```

I am getting error:
[image]

How I can sort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sort the queues by `totalItem` sum:

```
List<Queue<Sheeple>> sortedList = sheepleList.OrderBy(q => q.Sum(i => i.totalItem)).
                                              ToList();
```

Note that this creates a new list which you can assign to `sheepleList` if needed.

Comment: Can I ask you more favour? Can I override CompareTo of class Sheeple and do same thing?

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers The problem is that you want to sort by sum of `totalItem` which is only available from the collection (queue), not the `Sheeple` instances. You could implement your own `Queue<Sheeple>` class implementing `IComparable` based on your own rules but IMO it's totally overkill.

Comment: Ok. after checking your answers and looking into the document. I have now clear vision on difference between SORT and Orderby. thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
sheepleList = sheepleList.Sort(i => i.Sum(j => j.totalItem));
```

by

```
sheepleList = sheepleList.OrderBy(i => i.Sum(j => j.totalItem)).ToList();
```

The reason for this is that `Sort` is a method of `List<T>`, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.7.2), which takes an implementation of `Comparison` to take care of the ordering. As stated in the error message, the lambda expression you have provided instead cannot be converted to an implementation of `Comparison`. While your intention was sensible, the Linq extension method `Sort` has to be uses, which does exactly what you wand - mapping each instance of `Queue<Sheeple>` to `int`, which is then compared via `IComparable` (as a conversion to `Int32` is done under the hood).